# Prevent EditText from allowing more characters to be typed out based on rendering of Fonts

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, typeface

I have an item in a `RecyclerView` that gets rendered based on whether or not it has multiple words in it. If the item has multiple words, I assign a smaller typeface, if not then I assign a different typeface with a larger textsize.

## **Problem**:

I want the `EditText` to detect if the rendering for any given `TypeFace` is going to exceed a certain amount, if so then prevent the user from typing out anymore characters.

***Smaller TypeFace***:

- If the rendering exceeds 3 lines, do not let the user type in anymore characters

***Larger TypeFace***:

- If the rendering exceeds 1 line, do not let the user type in anymore characters.

## **Sample Drawing** (Just to be clear the EditText is not inside this layout):

**Smaller TypeFace**

[image]

**Larger TypeFace**

[image]

## **Initial Hunch**:

I am thinking that I create a custom `EditText` class and in that class get the `TypeFace` determine which kind it is and try to pre-render it. If the rendering exceeds the restrictions prevent anymore characters from being typed out.

Any thoughts on this?

Any ideas for implementation?

**Edit: I have a solution will be posting it up shortly**

Comment: I would look into using a combination of a TextWatcher and `EditText.getLayout()` to check the properties of the text layout. Using afterTextChanged() to handle character rejection, along with the Layout class's getLineCount() method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Layout.html) to figure out the line count should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Are you assuming the `EditText` is inside those layouts, if so that's not the case? Inside the item layouts there is a `TextView` that gets assigned the `EditText` characters.

Comment: The EditText has an internal class called Layout (that you can get with getLayout()) that handles all of the measurement and layout of the text.

Comment: Yes but I am not setting the custom typeface to the `EditText` view, but to another `TextView`.

Comment: So even if I get the measurements from the `EditText.getLayout()` it wouldn't be the same measurements as the other view. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: EditText extends TextView, and TextView has all of this as well. So you can set a watcher on the edit text that checks the layout of the other TextView if needed.

Comment: I see what you are implying though with the idea of the `TextWatcher`

Comment: You could also just create your own instance of Layout (StaticLayout or DynamicLayout) but I'm not familiar with exactly how much work that would entail.

Comment: Looking into it, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't the limit on the user text length absolute. Since you yourself switch between typeface. The absolute max length of user text is what you can fit in with smaller typeface. Where you switch from smaller to larger typeface is actually a lower limit of text length right?